# Add link over video on certain time

Tags: javascript, function, video, time, mp4

I would like to add a link over a video on a certain time, between seconds 6 and 12, for example. 
At the moment, I am getting the video current time, but I would like to do something like: if the video is playing between seconds 6 and 12, show this link.
This is my code:

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video id="myVideo" controls>
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div>Video current time: <p id="demo">0</p></div>

<div id="overlay">This is HTML overlay on top of the video! </div>


<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
    // Display the current position of the video in a <p> element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
    }

    //This piece of code is where I'm trying to display the link
    //**EDITED**
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    var video   = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
      var show = video.currentTime >= 5 && video.currentTime < 10;
        overlay.style.visibility= show ? 'visible' : 'visible';
    }, false);

</script>
```

Comment: refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful (I've edited my post with the code that you just gave me), but it seems that the code tries to show the "overlay" just between seconds 5 and 10, but that's not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an element and position it such that it overlays the video, and then remove this element once outside of the desired bounds in the video. However, it would be easier if you use a control that already does that like [this one (igVideoPlayer)](http://www.igniteui.com/video-player/banner-advertisements).

That control has banners and commercials that you can configure and is available freely (open source).

I made a change to your code:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";

var video   = document.getElementById('myVideo');

video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
  var show = video.currentTime >= 5 && video.currentTime < 10;
    overlay.style.visibility= show ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}, false);
```

It works for me in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZbkX/2974/).

Comment: Richardson gave me the same idea at the same time. I've edited my post, but it seems that the code tries to show the "overlay" just between seconds 5 and 10, but that's not working... Do you know why?

Comment: This is how it's working at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/ It's showing the "overlay" all the time, not just between certain seconds...

Comment: @patie I made some changes to your code and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'm afraid now is not showing the "overlay". I've created this codepen, so you can see the problem and modify the code if you need to

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong event, you should use `timeupdate` instead.

Here is another working code.

https://jsfiddle.net/miglpuc/ntx4fpb5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">










  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>








    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">




  <style type="text/css">
      #overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px; 
  color: #FFF; 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
  width: 640px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}

#v {
  z-index: 1;
}
  </style>

  <title>Overlay HTML over video player</title>






<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
  var overlay= document.getElementById('overlay');
  var video= document.getElementById('v');
  video.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};


    function myFunction() {

        var show = video.currentTime>=5 && video.currentTime<10;
        console.log(video.currentTime + ' >> ' + show)
        if(show) {
            $('#overlay').show();
        } else {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    }


}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
    <video id="v" controls="">
    <source id="webm" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm">

    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>


  </video>
  <div id="overlay" style='display: none;'>This is HTML overlay on top of the video! </div>






</body></html>
```

Comment: sorry i can't answer yesterday!

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful